# Hosting multiple websites in a BUCKET on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, bucket

I am working on an application where user can create his own html templates and publish them to the web.Now when the user clicks publish I want to create host his website on a subdomain with a name he selects.(EX: he names the site apple,I create a subdomain apple.ABC.com).
     In the application a single user can create multiple websites/templates.Now,I want to store a single users websites in a single bucket.If a user has two templates **Ex: apple.com and berry.com** ,I have two folders in the bucket,one for each website.But I went through the S3 bucket,and I found I can set hosting rules on the bucket and the website.
I wanted to understand if what I am trying is possible and if not how can I manage it as if I create one bucket for one template,it will be difficult for me to track which user has how many templates as in the DB I will have to have multiple entries.
I am aware I will have  to use AWS services and API's to store the templates to S3,I am interested if I can have multiple websites in a BUCKET.

**EDIT:Figured out a solution using proxy server nginx and updated the answer**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but doable.After some research I found a solution that can work.Steps are as follows:

1. We need a proxy server in order to perform the operations.(**eg:Nginx**)
2. We need to make config changes to the default.conf file to proxy requests to the bucket you have your website.
3. This is the conf file:

   ```
   server {
       # Listen on port 80 for all IPs associated with your machine
       listen 80;

       # Catch all other server names
       server_name _;

       # This code gets the host without www. in front and places it inside
       # the $host_without_www variable
       # If someone requests www.coolsite.com, then $host_without_www will have the value coolsite.com
       set $host_without_www $host;
       if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
           set $host_without_www $1;

       }

       location / {
           # This code rewrites the original request, and adds the host without www in front
           # E.g. if someone requests
           # /directory/file.ext?param=value
           # from the coolsite.com site the request is rewritten to
           # /coolsite.com/directory/file.ext?param=value
           set $foo 'http://sites.abcd.com';
           # echo "$foo";
           rewrite ^(.*)$ $foo/$host_without_www$1 break;


           # The rewritten request is passed to S3
           proxy_pass http://sites.abcd.com;
           include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now in your DNS settings change your CNAME to your proxy server address(Something like `router.abcd.com`).The proxy server will take your request and forward it to the S3 bucket where your site is hosted.
5. Also, you can use [wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com) ip address for `@` record.This will send your request to correct destination irrespective of the `www` in your URL.

Answer (score 4):

To use the static website feature of s3, you can only map one domain per bucket. There is no way to tell a domain to use the folder of the bucket instead of the bucket itself.