# Haproxy - how to do variable interpolation in url rewrites?

Tags: haproxy

How can I get the hostname of the current request and prepend it to the requested url? I  know how to rewrite the url, but not sure how can I get the hostname.

i'm try to achieve something like in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696506

I tried following, but the text `hdr(host)` is prepended to url, not hostname

```
reqrep ^/(.*)$ /hdr(host)\1 if ! je_sites
```

I'm using stable version of haproxy,